# ID card, driving license and debit card stolen in Kiev. What is the worst that can happen?

Tags: payment-cards, security, driving-licenses, ukraine, identity-cards

My dad is an EU citizen. His ID card, driving license and debit card were stolen in Kiev metro. So far we called the bank and informed the local police, he has his passport so he is ok to fly.

**Is there anything else that we should do in this kind of situation? What is the worst that can happen?**

Comment: Inspect bank statements closely for the next couple years if enough information was stolen to enable someone to impersonate him. Apart from that, not a ton you can do

Comment: In the UK there is a service (called Action Fraud) which can help in such cases if fraud is suspected. I do not know whether (a) they are any good (b) such a thing exists in your country but it might be worth typing identity fraud in your language into your favourite search engine to find out.

Comment: Contact the home country's government to advise them of the stolen ID card and driver license, so that they can flag them as invalid?

Comment: If they were stolen together with cash (i.e. in a wallet), most likely nothing would happen, and they all are already somewhere in the garbage can. According to UA police, pickpoketers usually throw away ASAP anything besides cash, because if caught, those would serve as evidence for pickpoketing.

Comment: We cannot possibly predict the worst that can happen. You've already done the basic steps (report theft to appropriate authorities) - what happens next is up to anyone's guess.